# How to add Container touch listener in codenameone framework

Tags: codenameone

i have use this code but not working properly

```
 public void actionPerformed(String which) {
               scrollView=which;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is completely incorrect. The signature for `actionPerformed` expects an `ActionEvent`. However, you can't just implement a method from an interface in an arbitrary class and hope it will be invoked.

You can track touch events on the form by adding a pointer listener to the parent form.

Comment: I need only Container Touch listener , if user click on container and i want to call one method for do some thing .  Please help me Shai Almog .

Comment: Container doesn't support that. I suggest you backtrack and explain what you are trying to do since containers aren't supposed to deal with user interaction.

Comment: We need a table created that has the following features:

Table must scroll in both X+Y directions

Column headers that do not scroll (in the Y direction) when the table scrolls.
Column headers that can be either labels or combo boxes.
Row headers that do not scroll (in the X direction) when the table scrolls.
Columns must have support for check boxes and combo boxes (depending on data)

Comment: Scrolling is seamless in TableLayout containers on X/Y, you can use the new ScrollListener interface to track scrolling on two separate containers one for the title and one for the body, that way the header/body can scroll together on the X axis. You can also use this with the Table class to get fixed headers (2 tables).

Comment: Shai Almog can you give me code for ScrollListener or any reference link, so i can implement my project properly  .

Comment: Searching the javadocs here https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html would lead you to https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#addScrollListener(com.codename1.ui.events.ScrollListener)

Comment: Thank you "Shai Almog" for give me suggestion  .

Answer (score 0):

AS Container is not a button we can't make on it an addActionListner so we must pass by the event "addPointerPressedListener as follows :

```
Container C1 = new Container ();
C1.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
//and you put here what to do once pressed on Container
                                            }
                    });
```